# How can I send notifications every minute to the telegram bot with PHP?

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

The scenario is as follows, I want to send messages or notifications (without commands sent by users) every minute on a Telegram channel.

It happens that I can send the messages every time I enter the URL and the message is sent, but I want it to be sent automatically (without entering the URL) every minute.  I do not know how to do that, thanks in advance.

```
<?php $botToken="<<BOT-TOKEN>>" ; $website="https://api.telegram.org/bot" .$botToken; $chatId="337957895" ; //**===>
```

> > NOTE: this chatId MUST be the chat_id of a person, NOT another bot chatId !!!** $params=[ 'chat_id'=>$chatId, 'text'=>'This is my message !!!', ]; $ch = curl_init($website . '/sendMessage'); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, ($params)); curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); $result = curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch); ?>

I have to enter the URL still for the message to be sent ...
https://bot.unpixelmas.com/bot.php

Comment: sounds like you want a cron job

Comment: I agree, you could use Curl or wget in a cron job.

Answer (score 1):

If we say that the URL you want to enter is `<YOUR CUSTOM URL>`, then you can make a PHP file and use the following code:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '<YOUR CUSTOM URL>',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);

?>
```

Then using `crontab -e` command you can open **cronjob** file and add your PHP file as record:

```
* * * * *  <PHP bin path> <your PHP source file path>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the URL is always the same, you should use [cronjob](https://cron-job.org/en/) and set it to open that URL every minute.